# Linq исключение ArgumentException при вызове Any()

Tags: c#, linq

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Делаю двойную сортировку на линке (приоритетный лист), сортирую, вывожу в `IEnumerable`, но при попытке `queue.Any()` бросается исключение `ArgumentException`. Гуглю уже полчаса, но причину так и не могу понять.

Помогите разобраться.

```
private readonly List<BaseBotAction> _actions = new List<BaseBotAction>(); // abstract

IEnumerable<BaseBotAction> queue = from action in _actions
    orderby action.Priority() ascending, action.StartTime ascending
    select action;

if (queue.Any()) { //ArgumentException here
    var action = queue.First();
    // Something...
}
```

Трейс:

```
2013-10-24 20:58:20,714 [Thread-Bot-Manager-PriorityQueue] ERROR EBot.ClientsManager [(null)] - System.ArgumentException: Длина результирующего массива недостаточна. Проверьте значения destIndex и length, а также нижние границы массива.
   в System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   в System.Collections.Generic.List`1.CopyTo(T[] array, Int32 arrayIndex)
   в System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   в System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   в EBot.BotInstance.PriorityQueueRun() в D:\CSharp\EBot\BotInstance.cs:строка 47
```

Comment: Напишите больше деталей по исключению, а? Message? InnerException? Stacktrace?

Comment: Совсем забыл... Разумеется, обновляю. Правда, хеш половину символов скушал, как обычно.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов: уж очень странное исключение случилось: внутри `order by` вдруг не хватило выделенного буфера. Либо в LINQ баг, либо каким-то образом поменялась коллекция во время выполнения `Any`.

---
Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исключение, судя по всему, бросается **не** в `Any()`, а при разворачивании `queue`. Попробуйте (временно, для теста) так:

```
IEnumerable<BaseBotAction> queue = (from action in _actions
    orderby action.Priority() ascending, action.StartTime ascending
    select action).ToList();
```

На этой строчке *уже* должно вылететь.

---

Кстати: а не обновляет ли случайно кто-то `_actions` из другого потока?

Comment: Таки да, забыл про синхронизацию, есть изменения из другого потока.